# GNOME pictures missing under Control Center

Tags: arch-linux, gnome

I'm using `GNOME 44.2` under `Arch Linux`. I did not install `GNOME` using the `gnome` group because I don't really use most of the applications installed by default — and if needed I can use their `Flatpak` counterparts.

I'm trying to fix a couple of issues I've seen, some of them might be related with the custom install, or not:

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ journalctl --boot --catalog --priority 3 
Jul 02 16:30:58 uplink kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Jul 02 16:30:58 uplink (sd-execu[288]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/ostree-system-generator failed with exit status 1.
Jul 02 16:31:07 uplink gdm-password][965]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 02 16:31:08 uplink systemd[1149]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 152 and the job result is failed.
Jul 02 16:31:08 uplink systemd[1149]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 156 and the job result is failed.
Jul 02 16:31:09 uplink pulseaudio[1403]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
```

But so far I'm unable to figure it out where the images from `GNOME Control Center` come from? I did install the package, so I would assume everything required for this to work correctly should come with it, or as a dependency.

[image]

[image]

While they should look like in these images:

1. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/2382
2. https://gitlab.gnome.org/Teams/Design/settings-mockups/-/blob/master/multitasking/multitasking.svg

This is what I used:

```bash
# pacman -Syu \
    adwaita-cursors adwaita-icon-theme \
    eog evince \
    file-roller \
    gdm \
    gnome-backgrounds gnome-console gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-shell gnome-system-monitor \
    man-db man-pages \
    nautilus networkmanager noto-fonts noto-fonts-cjk noto-fonts-emoji noto-fonts-extras \
    xdg-user-dirs-gtk
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to recover those files? I have posted the errors I encountered during the boot process because I'm not entirely sure how they might affect the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `gst-plugins-bad` package.

As a side note, if you are trying to do a lightweight installation of GNOME on arch, it would be better to install the `gnome` group and then uninstall the component you don't need. As GNOME is a rather complex, interdependent software system, a missing component can cause unexpected problems that take a lot of time to fix.

Comment: I was trying to avoid exactly these type of packages that _seems_ to add nothing. For instance, the system works fine (for me) without it, except for this one detail I spotted — but for sure I don't know if anything else might misbehave. Currently, `gst-plugins-bad` brings up `79` packages...but I guess there is no way round it :/

Comment: Does installing `gst-plugins-bad` solve the problem?

Comment: It's impossible to know what might go wrong, as many basic GNOME packages are not installed, e.g. `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome`, `gst-plugins`. It would be safer to install the `gnome` group and remove unneeded packages after extensive testing and bisection.

Comment: I was unable to figure it out what "single" package might solve this, so I installed `gst-plugins-bad` and all dependencies :/